# Как сделать такое на grid или flex

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Как отступать слева по максимальной ширине текста? Как это сделать без минимальной ширины текста [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как по мне тут простая таблица лучше подходит — она сходу решает этот вопрос, нет?

Comment: Хотелось бы научиться это делать на grid

Comment: Понял, хорошо, посмотрю что можно сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, не единственное решение, но я бы делал как-то так:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
    minmax(auto, 1fr)  /* 1 колонка */
    minmax(auto, 1fr); /* 2 колонка */
  width: fit-content; /* ширина всего грида */  
  background: #212a5f;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper div {
  padding: 5px; /* отступы от краев */
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: bold; /* первая колонка жирнее */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div>Позиция</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>Класс героя</div>
   <div>Хил</div>
   <div>Часов в игре</div>
   <div>567 часов</div>
   <div>Режим игры</div>
   <div>Аркада</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так и сделаю !

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь)

Comment: А зачем здесь используется `auto`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson в auto собственно весь смысл задачи, я бы еще подумал зачем тут 1fr , но это тот ответ который я дал и автора вопроса он устроил, Вы можете предложить свой ответ если у Вас есть предложения получше.